# Unity standalone exe crashes when switching between windows users

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, crash

How to reproduce the crash:

1- run the application from windows user A.

2- switch to windows user B without closing the application or sign out.

3- switch back to windows user A without closing the application.

After the investigation, it seems that the GPU is the main responsible for this.

Is there a way to know in Unity C# once the windows user is switched and how to reduce memory usage?
Noting that my application is running in the background.

The error I got is:
Access Violation (0xc0000005)

Comment: Sounds like a bug that needs to be reported to Unity.

Comment: It didn't happen on all computers.